# SQL Server 2012 Publisher SQL Server 2008 Subscriber version issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

So I have a setup where one virtual machine is a SQL Server 2012 publisher and I need to setup merge replication on a SQL Server 2008 subscriber on a different vm.

When setting up the subscription at the subscriber, during the wizard step where to add the SQL Server subscriber, I get that error :

> For merge publications, the version of the Subscriber must not exceed the version of the Publisher.

I read that SQL Server 2012 publishing supported 2008 and above subscribers.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What you have setup in sp_addmergepublication for @publication_compatibility_level ?

Comment: actually I didn't create the publication manually, but this parameter is set during the wizard steps anyway where I choose 2008 and above.. In any case I printed that value it's set to 100RTM..

Comment: This link is not exactly about SQL 2012 but it can help you to find how to test your publisher is configured to work with older SQL Server subscribers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx

Comment: This is because you are using SSMS 2008. Use T-SQL or SSMS 2012. Look at: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqlreplication.aspx?ID=ca830167-3993-4a2f-beb6-3697f9981086 Best Regards,
Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

It seems That this Problem is due to the SSMS versions. What you could do is create the subscription by right clicking on the Publication.

I assume you are using SQL 2012 as Distributor/Publisher & 2008 as Subscriber.